# What happens when you reverse time in Animal Crossing New Leaf?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I just got Animal Crossing New Leaf.

I only play very late at night, so most shops are closed and the residents are sleeping.

So I have decided to change the game's clock (at startup) and add about 8 hours.

Then I enter the game, and do my stuff.

My question is: if I ever want to fix the game's time (revert it to 8 hours back in time), what could be the negative effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following negative effects *could* happen (list adjusted to represent the 8 hour time travel backwards):

- More weeds (does not happen with Beautiful Town ordinance)
- Flowers will shrivel or die (does not happen with Beautiful Town ordinance)
- You could get Bed Hair
- Turnips will rot
- Cockroaches might appear in your character's house (does not happen with Beautiful Town ordinance)

Since you are only going 8 hours backwards, I doubt that there will be much weed or flowers that have died. The only effect that is guaranteed to happen is that the turnips will rot if you go back in time.

Sources:

[Animal Crossing Wikia](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Travel)

[Thonky.com](http://www.thonky.com/animal-crossing-new-leaf/stalk-market/)

Comment: But these only happen if you were to boot the game, and then roll the clock back 8 hours before you played. If you pushed the time forward 8 hours today and played. Then tomorrow, rolled the clock back before playing. Then there are no ill effects.